# Binomial sum only expanded, not computed

Tags: summation

I want to compute this sum: $\sum _{n=1}^4 \frac{(2 n-1) \sum _{k=0}^{n-1} \text{Binom}(6,k) \text{Binom}(10,-k+2 n-1)}{\text{Binom}(16,2 n-1)}$

`Sum[(2n-1)*(Sum[Binom[6,k]*Binom[10,2n-1-k],{k,0,n-1}])/(Binom[16,2n-1]),{n,1,4}]`

and get a fraction, but instead I get the sum expanded out (converted to LaTeX for readability):

$\frac{\text{Binom}(6,0) \text{Binom}(10,1)}{\text{Binom}(16,1)}+\frac{3 (\text{Binom}(6,1) \text{Binom}(10,2)+\text{Binom}(6,0) \text{Binom}(10,3))}{\text{Binom}(16,3)}+\frac{5 (\text{Binom}(6,2) \text{Binom}(10,3)+\text{Binom}(6,1) \text{Binom}(10,4)+\text{Binom}(6,0) \text{Binom}(10,5))}{\text{Binom}(16,5)}+\frac{7 (\text{Binom}(6,3) \text{Binom}(10,4)+\text{Binom}(6,2) \text{Binom}(10,5)+\text{Binom}(6,1) \text{Binom}(10,6)+\text{Binom}(6,0) \text{Binom}(10,7))}{\text{Binom}(16,7)}$.

I've tried basic stuff like Simplify, FullSimplify, and N, but each time it is left in this form or something similar. (I'm pretty new to Mathematica, so it's possible that I'm just missing some function.) How can I get it to output a number (preferably a fraction, but I guess a decimal is fine too)?

Comment: Note that the syntax coloring of `Binom` is blue indicating that it is undefined. If you highlight `Binom` and press `F1` for help, the first link should be for `Binomial`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Binom` is not valid Mathematica syntax. Try `Binomial` instead.

```
Sum[(2n-1)*(Sum[Binomial[6, k]*Binomial[10, 2 n-1-k], {k,0,n-1}])/(Binomial[16, 2 n-1]), {n,1,4}]
```

> 12245/1001